# invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Address

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to withdraw Eth and keep getting this issue

here is my code

```
      if withdraw.currency == 'eth' || withdraw.currency == 'mix' || withdraw.currency == 'usdt'
        balance = open("#{withdraw.channel.currency_obj.rest}/cgi-bin/total.cgi").read.rstrip.to_f
        raise Account::BalanceError, 'Insufficient coins' if balance < withdraw.sum

        fee = [withdraw.fee.to_f || withdraw.channel.try(:fee) || 0.0005, 0.1].min

        local_nonce = 0
        if withdraw.channel.currency_obj.code == "usdt"
          CoinRPC[withdraw.currency].personal_unlockAccount(withdraw.channel.currency_obj.base_account, "", 0)
          # get nonce
          local_nonce = CoinRPC[withdraw.currency].eth_getTransactionCount(withdraw.channel.currency_obj.base_account, "latest").to_i(16)
        else
          **CoinRPC[withdraw.currency].personal_unlockAccount(withdraw.channel.currency_obj.base_account, "", "0x30")**
          # get nonce
          local_nonce = CoinRPC[withdraw.currency].parity_nextNonce(withdraw.channel.currency_obj.base_account).to_i(16)
        end

        # calc amount
        gas_limit = withdraw.channel.currency_obj.gas_limit
        gas_price = withdraw.channel.currency_obj.gas_price
        #local_amount = (withdraw.amount * 1e18).to_i - (gas_price * gas_limit)
        
        txid = CoinRPC[withdraw.currency].eth_sendTransaction(from: withdraw.channel.currency_obj.base_account, to: withdraw.fund_uid, gas: "0x" + gas_limit.to_s(16), gasPrice: "0x" + gas_price.to_s(16), nonce: "0x" + local_nonce.to_s(16), value: "0x" + ((withdraw.amount * 1e18).to_i.to_s(16)))
      else
        balance = CoinRPC[withdraw.currency].getbalance.to_d
        raise Account::BalanceError, 'Insufficient coins' if balance < withdraw.sum

        fee = [withdraw.fee.to_f || withdraw.channel.try(:fee) || 0.0005, 0.1].min

        # CoinRPC[withdraw.currency].settxfee fee
        @amount = (withdraw.amount*100000000.0).round / 100000000.0
        txid = CoinRPC[withdraw.currency].sendtoaddress withdraw.channel.currency_obj.base_secret, withdraw.fund_uid, @amount.to_f
```

and here is the log error

```
        I, [2022-08-29T07:25:10.189241 #29938]  INFO -- : ETH {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":[17958023718327819853794372076217808889400833786,"","0x30"],"id":"1"}
I, [2022-08-29T07:25:10.191302 #29938]  INFO -- : {"jsonrpc"=>"2.0", "id"=>"1", "error"=>{"code"=>-32602, "message"=>"invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Address"}}
I, [2022-08-29T07:25:10.191448 #29938]  INFO -- : [error]: {"code"=>-32602, "message"=>"invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Address"}
```

Comment: Try logging `withdraw.channel.currency_obj.base_account` and see what it is. Looks like it's not an address string, but a number value of some sort. It's the first value in the `params` part of the error log

Comment: thanks the issue is resolved and now getting   I, [2022-08-30T11:04:48.800178 #12115]  INFO -- : ETH {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":["0x03xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","",48],"id":"1"}
I, [2022-08-30T11:04:48.801525 #12115]  INFO -- : {"jsonrpc"=>"2.0", "id"=>"1", "error"=>{"code"=>-32000, "message"=>"account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden"}}
I, [2022-08-30T11:04:48.801629 #12115]  INFO -- : [error]: {"code"=>-32000, "message"=>"account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden"

Comment: You're using HTTP for account unlocking so you'll need to add the flag `--allow-insecure-unlock` to your geth launch command

Comment: Frankly though, I tend to suggest against using Geth's built in account manager. It's not the most secure route to go